# Daphne on Elastic beanstalk - WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, daphne

Following this guide https://medium.com/@elspanishgeek/how-to-deploy-django-channels-2-x-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-8621771d4ff0 to set up a django app that uses websockets.

01_env.config

```
option_settings:  
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: dashboard.settings
    PYTHONPATH: /opt/python/current/app/dashboard:$PYTHONPATH
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: dashboard/wsgi.py

  aws:elbv2:listener:80:
    DefaultProcess: http
    ListenerEnabled: 'true'
    Protocol: HTTP
    Rules: ws
  aws:elbv2:listenerrule:ws:
    PathPatterns: /websockets/*
    Process: websocket
    Priority: 1
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:http:
    Port: '80'
    Protocol: HTTP
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:websocket:
    Port: '5000'
    Protocol: HTTP
```

02_setup.config

```
container_commands:
  00_pip_upgrade:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade pip"
    ignoreErrors: false
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  02_collectstatic:
    command: "django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput"
  03_wsgipass:
    command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
  04_celery_tasks:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/celery_configuration.txt > /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh && chmod 744 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh"
    leader_only: true
  05_celery_tasks_run:
    command: "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh"
    leader_only: true
```

03_proxy.config

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      ProxyPass /websockets/ ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/
      ProxyPassReverse /websockets/ ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/
```

When opening the websocket I get the message on chrome's console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://xx.xx.xx.elasticbeanstalk.com/websockets/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

Logs indicate:

```
AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /websockets/ (scheme 'ws'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

Loaded apache modules listed on the EC2 instance by running `sudo apachectl -M`:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 allowmethods_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_dbd_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_socache_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_dbd_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 cache_disk_module (shared)
 cache_socache_module (shared)
 data_module (shared)
 dbd_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 dumpio_module (shared)
 echo_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 http2_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 macro_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 remoteip_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 request_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_plain_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 socache_dbm_module (shared)
 socache_memcache_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 watchdog_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 lua_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 lbmethod_heartbeat_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_hcheck_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_uwsgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 wsgi_module (shared)
```

Turning on Apache's debug mode, I also get in the logs:

```
AH02900: declining URL ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/  (not WebSocket, Upgrade: header is missing)
```

Google chrome's console shows me the following request for the websocket:

[image]

Daphne is listening to 0.0.0.0:5000 and the console indicates no call whatsoever to the websocket -> the problem is somewhere in the configuration of the Apache server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it changing my 03_proxy.config to:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      ProxyPass /websockets/ ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ upgrade=NONE
      ProxyPassReverse /websockets/ ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/
      #Uncomment below for Option 3
      #ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
      #ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

Also needed to change asgi.py to:

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'dashboard.settings')

django.setup()

application = get_default_application()
```